# How can I get flag count of a flag?

Tags: 8, flags

I see extensive Drupal 7 documentation for the Flags module, but very little for Drupal 8. 
I have a Signup flag on a Drupal 8 node (which is an event). I need to suppress the Signup link when a number of signups (flags) have been added to this node.

I'm trying with `hook_preprocess_flag()` using the following code.

```
$flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
$flag = $flag_service->getFlagById('signup');
```

What call gets the flag_count of that flag?

Comment: $flag_service = Drupal::service('flag.count');
$counts = $flag_service->getEntityFlagCounts($node);

Comment: Or if you want it for flag entity use $flag_service ->getFlagFlaggingCount($flag);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For flag count on entities use:

```
$flag_service = Drupal::service('flag.count');
$counts = $flag_service->getEntityFlagCounts($node);
```

For flag count on flag entity use:

```
$flag_service->getFlagFlaggingCount($flag);
```

You can find all functions from the Service here:

/modules/contrib/flag/src/FlagCountManager.php

Comment: Thank you @Insasse, this solved my problem!

Comment: Hi, if I use the above code : $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag.count'); $flag_count = $flag_service->getFlagFlaggingCount('flag_machine_name'); I get this error : TypeError : Argument 1 passed to Drupal\flag\FlagCountManager::getFlagFlaggingCount() must implement interface Drupal\flag\FlagInterface, string given,.... How Can I get the number of flagged nodes for a flag type? Thanks.

Comment: $flag = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagById('flag_machine_name');