# How can I limit flagging per user?

Tags: 8, users, flags

Node compare is awesome plugin but it's just only in D7.

I'm using Drupal 8.

I have a views page which integrated with flag(compare it) and flipped table module  to compare contents. It has limit to show max. 4 content. Everything works until this point.

But how can  limit user to flagging max. 4 times. Flag limit is nice in D7 but it's not ported in D8.And I couldn't achieved it via rules integration.
Any help with this would be awesome . Thanks

Comment: This would be a start, [How can I get flag_count of a flag?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278285/how-can-i-get-flag-count-of-a-flag)

Comment: I can get flag count. What's next ? I couldn't find how to restrict user to flagging after 4th.

Comment: just use diff and some views